# Get Image Size Without Loading The Image

Tags: image, swift, size, skspritenode

I currently using the below to get the size of an image. But I would like to do this without creating the sprite node, if that make sense.

```
let nodeImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "nodeImage")
let nodeWidth = nodeImage.size.width
let nodeHeight = nodeImage.size.height
```

What I would like is something that access the images file and just simply find out the size of specific image. Something like the below (clearly this doesn't work, just an example)

```
let nodeHeight = (imageNamed: "nodeImage").size.height
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`UIImage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/) class. It has e init method similar to that of `SKSpriteNode`:

```
UIImage(named name: String)
```

And then you can use the `size` property of the UIImage to obtain the height in points of the image.

Comment: Wow, that was simple. Thanks, this is going to help me out a lot.